# QueryFullProcessImageName failing with valid HINSTANCE?

Tags: c, winapi

```
//window is an HWND
LPWSTR path = new WCHAR[1024];
DWORD  size = 1024;

GetWindowText(window, path, 1024);

HINSTANCE instance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(window, GWLP_HINSTANCE);

QueryFullProcessImageName(instance, PROCESS_NAME_NATIVE, path, &size);
```

This code fails on the call to QueryFullProcessImageName(...) with an error code 6 [invalid handle].  GetWindowText succeeds, and GetWindowLong returns a non-zero HINSTANCE.

I'm pretty new to win32, so why this isn't working is beyond me.  I believe both the HWND and HINSTANCE involved are valid...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Main problem:**

For the function: [QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919(VS.85).aspx), the first parameter is not an HINSTANCE, it is the process handle.  They are different.   To get the current process Id you should use [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(VS.85).aspx).  Then pass that into [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx) to get the process handle.

---

**Other Problem:**

You should be using [GetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585(VS.85).aspx) above instead of GetWindowLong.  Using GetWindowLong would likely cause problems on x64 systems.

---

**How to find out what your problem is on your own:**

After most Win32 functions fail, you can find out the reason why by using GetLastError.

So after the call to QueryFullProcessImageName please do this:

```
DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
std::string strErrorMessage;
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwLastError, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,    0, NULL);
if (lpMsgBuf)
{
    strErrorMessage = (const TCHAR*)lpMsgBuf;
    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}
```

You can also simply just call GetLastError() and [lookup its return value here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Fixed code:
DWORD processID = 0;
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &processID);
 HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, processID);

QueryFullProcessImageName(processHandle, PROCESS_NAME_NATIVE, path, &size);

Thanks.